# A quick way to get the mean of each position in large RDD

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have a large RDD (more than 1,000,000 lines), while each line has four elements `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` in a tuple. A head scan of the RDD looks like

```
[(492,3440,4215,794),
(6507,6163,2196,1332),
(7561,124,8558,3975),
(423,1190,2619,9823)]
```

Now I want to find the mean of each position in this RDD. For example for the data above I need an output list has values:

```
(492+6507+7561+423)/4
(3440+6163+124+1190)/4
(4215+2196+8558+2619)/4
(794+1332+3975+9823)/4
```

which is:

```
[(3745.75,2729.25,4397.0,3981.0)]
```

Since the RDD is very large, it is not convenient to calculate the sum of each position and then divide by the length of RDD. Are there any quick way for me to get the output? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything faster than calculating the mean (or sum) for each column
If you are using the DataFrame API you can simply aggregate multiple columns:

```
import os
import time

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# start local spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# load as rdd
def localpath(path):
    return 'file://' + os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir), path)

rdd = spark._sc.textFile(localpath('myPosts/'))

# create data frame from rdd
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
means_df = df.agg(*[f.avg(c) for c in df.columns])
means_dict = means_df.first().asDict()
print(means_dict)
```

Note that the dictionary keys will be the default spark column names ('0', '1', ...). If you want more speaking column names you can give them as an argument to the createDataFrame command

Comment: Hi, my data is in RDD.Could you please tell me how to convert it to DataFrame format? Thank you very muh.

Comment: I've edited and included how to create the DF from RDD

Comment: What is the `spark` here? When I run the code an error appears: `name 'spark' is not defined`.

Comment: it's the SparkSession: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession
If you're using spark 1.x you need a SqlContext

Comment: Could you please write a full version of the code? Since I am not familiar with Spark I also stuck at the building session part. When I tried to use `spark = SparkSession.builder()` another error appears `name 'SparkSession' is not defined`

Comment: could you please provide your code? How do you create the RDD? Do you run in the pyspark-shell or via spark-submit?

Comment: `from pyspark import SparkContext`.`sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "temp")`. `import os,time`.
`def localpath(path):
    return 'file://' + os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir), path)` . `rdd = sc.textFile(localpath('myPosts/'))` That is the code I used to convert the data into RDD